# How to change column names of last 7 columns of pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am running a loop and adding 7 new columns to an existing DataFrame. After each iteration of the loop, I want to change column names of only the new columns added (i.e. last 7 columns). I have tried doing this using following line of code:

```
df.columns[len(df.columns)-6:len(df.columns)] = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7']
```

This line of code is not working and I am getting an error -

> Index does not support mutable operations

I have looked up on various sites but none of the methods help my case. What can I do to change name of only last 7 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the columns into a list with `df.columns.tolist()`, modify the list instead of `df.columns` itself, and then assign the list back to `df.columns`:

```py
columns = df.columns.tolist()
columns[len(columns)-6:len(columns)] = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7']
df.columns = columns
```

Comment: Python supports negative indexing so `columns[-6:] = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7']` is fine. Also just `df.columns.values[-6:] = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7']` works.